# Can't use setForeground method on ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I want to use the setForeground method to show a "play" icon in the center of my ImageView to indicate the user that a video will play if they press it.

Currently I'm having this error which I cannot solve:

[image]

Although the documentation says the method should be available since API 1:

[image]

I'm targeting and compiling against API 23 with build tools version 23.0.1. I'm targeting min API 16.

Comment: This question already has answers here:
[Why doesn't `android:foreground` attribute work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411921/7594961)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That is [a documentation bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186273). `setForeground()` existed on `FrameLayout` from API Level 1; it is only on `View` as of API Level 23.

Comment: Alright thanks, do you have any suggestion on how to get the play icon then in my case? I'm currently thinking manually merging the regular image and the foreground image might be my only choice, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Saragis: Off the cuff, have the "regular image" be the background image of the `ImageView`, and have the play icon be the actual image for the `ImageView`

Comment: this answer little not correct. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setForeground at kitkat(19).

Comment: @bongjaechoe: As my answer states, `setForeground()` was added to `View` on API Level 23. You are attempting to  use it on API Level 19. API Level 19 came out years before API Level 23, and so `setForeground()` was not available on `View` at the time.

Comment: If you wrap the view inside a `FrameLayout` and use `setForground` to the layout, the warning will disappear!

Answer (score 6):

Since the `setForeground` method was added for the `FrameLayout` in API Level 1, as a workaround you can wrap your view inside a `FrameLayout` then use the `setForeground` method to the layout, it will work, eg:

in your xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fl_item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/niImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageView_description"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in code, use:

```
holder.flItemContainer.setForeground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(a, R.drawable.play));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can either change

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

with

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

or `import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;`
to your class and this statement

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

to the activity you used `setForground` method in it.

Note that `M` in `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` stands for API 23

and you can use each one of the items below that each one stand for a specific API instead of `M`

> BASE       1
>   BASE_1_1       2
>   CUPCAKE       3
>   DONUT       4
>   ECLAIR       5
>   ECLAIR_0_1       6
>   ECLAIR_MR1       7
>   FROYO       8
>   GINGERBREAD       9
>   GINGERBREAD_MR1       10
>   HONEYCOMB       11
>   HONEYCOMB_MR1       12
>   HONEYCOMB_MR2       13 
>   ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH       14
>   ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1       15
>   JELLY_BEAN       16
>   JELLY_BEAN_MR1       17
>   JELLY_BEAN_MR2       18
>   KITKAT       19
>   KITKAT_WATCH       20
>   LOLLIPOP       21
>   LOLLIPOP_MR1       22
>   M       23
>   N       24
>   N_MR1       25
>   O       26
>   CUR_DEVELOPMENT       10000

Comment: No, this is a documentation bug like mentioned in a previous answer. It should be fixed soon by Google (hopefully).