# 'Call requires API level 23' error, but getForeground() exists on FrameLayout from API 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-framelayout, android-api-levels

**Summary**

Finally, I found the related issue, `setForeground()` incorrectly flagged as requiring API 23 on ViewGroups extending `FrameLayout`.

[Issue 189041:  setForeground() incorrectly flagged as requiring API 23 (NewApi) for ViewGroups extending FrameLayout](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189041)

If you are not extending `FrameLayout`, the documentation is wrong and API 23 is required.

[Issue 186273:  View.setForeground wrong API level](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186273)

**Updated question**

Marked as [duplicated of Can't use `setForeground` method on ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33201753/1009132) by Commonsware and answered by him:

> That is a documentation bug. setForeground() existed on FrameLayout
>   from API Level 1; it is only on View as of API Level 23.

In my case the documentation bug is not detected by the inspection in the fork but does it in an integration project, I don't understand it, anyway, this answers my initial question.

But It's not the same case, this code is already extending a `Framelayout` and using this method, it's not an `ImageView`, so I suppose the method has been removed in API 23. It doesn't appear in the reference now.

**Update:** I add a [diff report](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html) for FrameLayout:

[image]

**New question**

So my question changes to how to use the method in previous versions, and, why does appear the inspection error selectively?

If I add a redundant cast, the error message disappears:

```
((FrameLayout) layout).getForeground()
```

But it's accessing the `View` method that is not supported now.

So I suppose targeting a previous API would remove the error message but I would appreciate a solution to use this Framelayout method or a clue to fix the issue in my case:

```
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.1
ANDROID_DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
```

**Workaround**

In short, as a workaround, I changed the type to `FrameLayout` directly, so warnings about API and casting are gone, and I tested it works on Android 4.4.4 device and debugging, I thought it would crash, anyway it's only used in one animation, and I will fix/replace it in the future.

**Initial question**

I forked and customised the Google sample [android-topeka](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/topeka/widget/quiz/AbsQuizView.java#L89), and android-studio shows an error that I don't understand about the API level required to use the method `getForeground()` of the class `View` in `android.view` package:

> Call requires API level 23 (current min is 19):
>   android.view.View#getForeground

The [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getForeground()) marks the method as added in API level 1, and the documentation (`Control+Q`) shows the same:

[image: Doc showing API level 1 method]

But the `Calling new methods on older versions inspection` shows an error that API level 23 is required:

[image: Error message about API 23 required]

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591672/android-studio-call-requires-api-level-16-error),  a bug in that case, but I think this is not a bug due to the original fork doesn't show this error message.

I'll try to detect the first time the message appears, but I did a lot of changes so any clue would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I found the related issue, `setForeground()` incorrectly flagged as requiring API 23 for ViewGroups extending `FrameLayout`.

[Issue 189041:  setForeground() incorrectly flagged as requiring API 23 (NewApi) for ViewGroups extending FrameLayout](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189041)

If you are not extending `FrameLayout`, the documentation is wrong and API 23 is really required.

[Issue 186273:  View.setForeground wrong API level](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186273)

Comment: So did you figure out how can we get or set foreground for devices below API 23?

Comment: If you are extending a FrameLayout, you can use a redundant cast or change the type to FrameLayout to avoid the documentation bug. Otherwise, it's not possible, but maybe the next workaround is useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/33201753/1009132

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54905241/2268466) as a workaround

Comment: Thanks, nice, related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52329249/1009132) as well