# How do you setForeground for android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout on API 16

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-framelayout

I'm targeting API 23.

Previously, I am using `FrameLayout`'s `setForeground` method in device with API 16 without any issues.

Recently, I migrate `FrameLayout` to `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`, with intention to continue support for device with API 16.

To my surprise, `setForeground` for `View`, is only available since API 23.

Also, bug in documentation will give you lotsa headache - [Call requires API level 23: getForeground() error, but is a FrameLayout method since API 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379534/call-requires-api-level-23-getforeground-error-but-is-a-framelayout-method-s)

So, may I know how do you perform `setForeground` on `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`, for device with API 16?

`ViewCompat` doesn't help much, as it doesn't contain `setForeground` method.

Comment: You could wrap the `CoordinatorLayout` in a `FrameLayout`, or subclass `CoordinatorLayout`, and handle drawing the foreground yourself after the `super` call in `dispatchDraw()`.