# Why doesn't `android:foreground` attribute work?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Take a look at this small android app:

MainActivity.java:

```
package io.github.gsaga.toucheventtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

The image pointed to by `android:foreground` isn't displayed, but it appears if I change `foreground` to `src` or `background` in `activity_main.xml`. This code seems to follow the instructions described here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:foreground

Why doesn't the `android:foreground` tag work in above code?

**NOTE:**

`minSdkVersion` is `19`, I'm running this app on `Android 5.1` (`API level 22`)

Comment: In Which API version you are running the app?

Comment: @HarishJose `minSdkVersion` is 19, I'm running this app on android 5.1

Comment: @saga Hi, can you please specify the actual intention of the post? Are you are trying to set an overlay to an ImageView or to figure out why `android:foreground` attribute isn't working for `ImageViews` out of curiosity ?

Comment: Hello, @saga. you should use the `android:foreground` at `FrameLayout`, please.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Short answer

This is due to a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37065042) which existing in Android since API level 23.

## More details on the behavior

Here is the list of all the XML attributes and corresponding methods related to setting foreground drawables to views with the API level they are introduced through `FrameLayout`. However, these are later moved into `View` in API level 23.

```
╔════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║       XML attribute        ║                     Method                      ║   Added in  ║
║                            ║                                                 ║ (API level) ║
╠════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ android:foreground         ║ setForeground(Drawable)                         ║ 1           ║
╠════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ android:foregroundGravity  ║ setForegroundGravity(int gravity)               ║ 1           ║
╠════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ android:foregroundTint     ║ setForegroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode tintMode) ║ 21          ║
╠════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ android:foregroundTintMode ║ setForegroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode tintMode) ║ 21          ║
╚════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

- Android doc says `setForeground(Drawable)` is added in API 1 and `setForegroundTintList (ColorStateList tint)` and  `setForegroundTintMode (PorterDuff.Mode tintMode)` are added in API level 21 to `View`. Actually they were there in `FrameLayout` until it moved in API 23.
- In API level < 23, you will get a warning even though it is not required. You can just suppress it. See [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37065042).

Now take a look at how these properties work on different versions.

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ API level ║      By code     ║     Using XML    ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ <23       ║ FrameLayout only ║ FrameLayout only ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ >=23      ║ FrameLayout only ║ All views        ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

## The cause of the bug

When these properties moved to `View` in API level 23, they did some strange modifications on it which can be called a bug. While loading properties from XML, it checks whether the `View` is a `FrameLayout` which is not present inside the methods we can use for the same purpose.

View constructor, API level 23:

```
case R.styleable.View_foreground:
    if (targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M || this instanceof FrameLayout) {
        setForeground(a.getDrawable(attr));
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 12):

To use `android:foreground` on `Android 5.1` i.e. `API level 22`, you are not using [`android:foreground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:foreground) correctly.

As it's name clearly indicating that you can set drawable on the top/foreground of any content like overlay i.e you can put some view in `FrameLayout` in that you can use `android:foreground`. Inside this FrameLayout add your `ImageView`.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:foreground):

> Defines the drawable **to draw over the content**. This can be used as
>   an **overlay**. The foreground drawable participates in the padding of
>   the content if the gravity is set to fill.

Below is usage example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ic_launcher_background>

    // your ImageView here
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Note:** 
For `API level > 23` it will work without `FrameLayout`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: The documentation states the `android:foreground` `defines  the drawable to draw over the content`, it doesn't state anywhere that the content has to be a `ViewGroup`. And the tag is defined for the `View` class. If what you're saying is correct then the tag should've been defined for the `ViewGroup` class.

Comment: @saga I agree that documentation is not clear enough but my solution is for `Android 5.1` i.e. `API level 22` (where you are facing the issue). Yes you are right that documentation is not clear enough for usage of `android:foreground` property. For `API level > 23` it will work without `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like at one time (API <23) that `android:foreground` would work with only `FrameLayout` as VicJordan suggests. However, for API 23+ it appears that `android:foreground` will work for any view type. See [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#5414) selection from the **View.java** source:

```
case R.styleable.View_foreground:
    if (targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M || this instanceof FrameLayout) {
        setForeground(a.getDrawable(attr));
}
```

Here is an example of `android:foreground` working on API 28 with the following layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Yet, on API 22, we see this:

[image]

No foreground image. So, `android:foreground` works only when the API level is 23+. I agree that this is not really documented, but that is just the way it is.

**Update:** API 23 seems to have an issue with `android:foreground`, so let's say `android:foreground` works on API 24+ for general views.

**Second update:** Came across a couple of other posts addressing this same issue regarding `setForeground()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379534/call-requires-api-level-23-error-but-getforeground-exists-on-framelayout-fr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201712/cant-use-setforeground-method-on-imageview). In the accepted answer to the second question, CommonsWare identifies this as a "documentation bug."

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to wrap your image with a `<ripple>`, set it as your `ImageView`'s `background`, and use `tint` and `tintMode` to "hide" the `src` image so the background image that has the ripple over it is visible.

```xml
<!-- In your layout file -->

<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_with_ripple"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:tint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:tintMode="src_in" />
```

```xml
<!-- drawable/image_with_ripple.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?colorControlHighlight">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />

</ripple>
```

Not only this **works on API 21+** but if your image has rounded corners – or is another type of non-rectangle shape, like a star or a heart icon – the **ripple will remain in its bounds** instead of filling the view's rectangle bounds, which gives a better look in some cases.

See [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@flawyte/android-best-way-to-add-a-ripple-to-an-imageview-a8345e499a64) for an animated GIF to see how this technique compares to using a `<FrameLayout>` or the `foreground` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constraint layout and items are drawn top to bottom of the layout.xml hence the elements at the end of the file are drawn last and appear on top I kept the gravity properties in the file in case it starts working in a future version.

[image]

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text = "Sample Color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/word_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="Hello Word what do you think is happening here"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/edit_text_selector"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```